# How to fix "Internal error in server" in Google Sandbox Checkout?

Tags: curl, google-checkout

I am including post cart information in xml file  then use curl's @ option to post the contents of the file, Here is the example:

```
curl -d /home/test/Downloads/sampcodetest.xml  https://xxx:yyy@sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/request/Merchant/xxx

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2" serial-number="fb8c82e7-1e52-4e7f-b0e1-6394cc3f328a">
  <error-message>Internal error in server</error-message>
</error>
```

I am passing valid merchant id and key.

Answer (score 1):

In the Merchant Center look under Tools->Integration Console and see if there is any additional info there.

This error may show up if there is a mismatch between sandbox IDs and posting URL. You also need to create a buyer sandbox account.